# script timeout exeption is thrown when we try to execute " JSONObject responseJSON = new AXE.Builder(driver, scriptUrl).analyze();"

Tags: selenium, accessibility

I have used Axe core in selenium framework when it tries to execute:

```
[JSONObject responseJSON = new AXE.Builder(driver, scriptUrl).analyze();
```

Below exception is thrown:

> 16:39:26:09-12-2019>>org.openqa.selenium.ScriptTimeoutException: script timeout
>     (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
>   System info: host: 'L3DV3N62', ip: '10.93.47.117', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 78.0.3904.108, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a81..., userDataDir: C:\Users\SSUPAR~1.TEM\AppDa...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61391}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
>   Session ID: c3e0abe6c1b2ca3a34b765b70cc594df
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeAsyncScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:506)
>       at com.deque.axe.AXE$Builder.execute(AXE.java:372)
>       at com.deque.axe.AXE$Builder.analyze(AXE.java:335)
>       at Driver.Reuse.analyzeViolations(Reuse.java:6146)
>       at AppLib.AnalyzeViolation.ExecuteComponent(AnalyzeViolation.java:25)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at AppLib.Reflection.execute(Reflection.java:26)
>       at Driver.Demo1.testDemo1(Demo1.java:1130)
>       at Driver.Demo1.main(Demo1.java:748)

Comment: You should add a tag for the programming language you are using. If there is an Axe related tag, you should add that too to get it to the right readers that can help.

Answer (score 1):

Below timeout setting works for me:

```java
JSONObject responseJSON = new AXE.Builder(driver, scriptURL)
    .options("{ runOnly: { type: 'tag', values: ['wcag2a','wcag2aa'] } }")
    .setTimeout(60000).analyze();
```

Comment: This is not an answer, please comment on another answer or the question itself.